# Typical lower bound of a analytical number theory problems and prime gap.

Tags: solution-verification, integers

Define $$\Pi=\Pi_1\cup\Pi_2\cup\Pi_3$$
Where, $$\Pi_1=\{6mn-m+n|m, n\in \mathbb{N}\}$$
$$\Pi_2=\{6mn-m-n|m, n\in \mathbb{N}\}$$
$$\Pi_3=\{6mn+m+n|m, n\in \mathbb{N}\}$$.
Note that a twin prime pair other than $(3, 5)$ must be of the form $(6n-1, 6n+1)$.
Hence if there are finitely many twin primes we must have $k\in \Pi$ for all $k>j\in\mathbb{N}$.Thus we have $\{1,2,3, ..., j\}\cup\Pi=\mathbb{N}$

We know $$\sum_{t=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{t^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$$

Thus we have $$\sum_{d=1}^{j} \frac{1}{d^2}+\sum_{d=j+1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{d^2}=\sum_{d=1}^{j} \frac{1}{d^2}+\sum_{x\in{(\Pi_1)_{>j}}} \frac{1}{x^2}+\sum_{y\in{(\Pi_2\cup\Pi_3)}_{>j},y\notin{\Pi_1}_{> j} } \frac{1}{y^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$$
Now $$1+\sum_{d=2}^{j}(\frac{1}{d}-\frac{1}{1+d})\leq 1+\sum_{d=2}^{j} \frac{1}{d^2}\leq
1+\sum_{d=2}^{j}(\frac{1}{d-1}-\frac{1}{d})$$
Further more,
$$\frac{3}{2}-\frac{1}{j+1}\leq \sum_{d=1}^{j} \frac{1}{d^2}\leq
2-\frac{1}{j}$$

$$\frac{\pi^2}{6}-2+\frac{1}{j}\leq \sum_{x\in{(\Pi_1)_{>j}}} \frac{1}{x^2}+\sum_{y\in{(\Pi_2\cup\Pi_3)}_{>j},y\notin{\Pi_1}_{>j} } \frac{1}{y^2}\leq \frac{\pi^2}{6}-\frac{3}{2}+\frac{1}{j+1}$$

Let the expression,
$$\mu_j=\sum_{x\in{(\Pi_1)_{>j}}} \frac{1}{x^2}+\sum_{y\in{(\Pi_2\cup\Pi_3)}_{> j},y\notin{\Pi_1}_{>j} } \frac{1}{y^2}$$

Also,
$$\mu^{*}_j=\sum_{x\in{(\Pi_1)_{>j}},x\notin(\Pi_2\cup\Pi_3)_{> j}} \frac{1}{x^2}+\sum_{y\in{(\Pi_2\cup\Pi_3)}_{> j} } \frac{1}{y^2}$$

Note that $\mu^{*}_j=\mu_{j}$
Thus,  $$2\mu_{j}=\mu^{*}_j+\mu_{j}=
\sum_{x\in{(\Pi_1)_{>j}},x\notin(\Pi_2\cup\Pi_3)_{>j}} \frac{1}{x^2}+\sum_{y\in{(\Pi_2\cup\Pi_3)}_{> j} } \frac{1}{y^2}+
\sum_{x\in{(\Pi_1)_{>j}}} \frac{1}{x^2}+\sum_{y\in{(\Pi_2\cup\Pi_3)}_{> j},y\notin{\Pi_1}_{>j} } \frac{1}{y^2}\geq\sum_{a\in(\Pi_1)_{>j}} \frac{1}{a^2}+\sum_{b\in(\Pi_2\cup\Pi_3)_{>j}} \frac{1}{b^2}=\chi_{j}$$

Now,
$$\frac{1}{25}\sum_{a\in \Pi_1}\frac{1}{a^2}+\frac{1}{25}\sum_{b\in(\Pi_2\cup\Pi_3)} \frac{1}{b^2}>U=\sum_{6k-1=\text{composite}} \frac{1}{(6k-1)^2}+\sum_{6k+1=\text{composite}} \frac{1}{(6k+1)^2}=(1-\frac{1}{2^2})(1-\frac{1}{3^2})\zeta(2)-\sum_{p\in\mathbb{P}_{\geq 5}}\frac{1}{p^2}$$

$$U=\sum_{6k-1=\text{composite}} \frac{1}{(6k-1)^2}+\sum_{6k+1=\text{composite}} \frac{1}{(6k+1)^2}>\frac{1}{49}\sum_{a\in \Pi_1}\frac{1}{a^2}+\frac{1}{49}\sum_{b\in(\Pi_2\cup\Pi_3)} \frac{1}{b^2}$$

Hence, $$\chi_j=\sum_{a\in(\Pi_1)} \frac{1}{a^2}+\sum_{b\in(\Pi_2\cup\Pi_3)} \frac{1}{b^2}-\sum_{a\in(\Pi_1)_{\leq j}} \frac{1}{a^2}-\sum_{b\in(\Pi_2\cup\Pi_3)_{\leq j}} \frac{1}{b^2}$$

Now,  Note that,  $$\frac{3}{100}<\sum_{p\in\mathbb{P}_{\geq 5}}\frac{1}{p^2}=F<\frac{35}{100}$$

(Got the value of $F$ from Wikipedia)
But, $$\sum_{a\in(\Pi_1)} \frac{1}{a^2}+\sum_{b\in(\Pi_2\cup\Pi_3)} \frac{1}{b^2}>25U>\frac{(25\times 3\times8\times\pi^2)-(216\times 8.75)}{216}>18$$

Now,  $$
\sum_{a\in(\Pi_1)_{\leq j}} \frac{1}{a^2}+\sum_{b\in(\Pi_2\cup\Pi_3)_{\leq j}} \frac{1}{b^2}<\sum_{l=1}^{j} \frac{2}{l^2}\leq 4-\frac{2}{j}$$
Thus,
$$\chi_{j}>14+\frac{2}{j}$$
Hence,  $$\mu_{j}>7+\frac{1}{j}>\frac{\pi^2}{6}-\frac{3}{2}+\frac{1}{j+1}$$
A contradiction!!!

Can you guys check if it's correct,  Thanks in advance. Please do as much as criticism in the proof,  I will not mind anything cause,  I need a good solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As an aside, you could use something like $x^2=s^3+2s^2+st+t$ to capture all twin prime pairs $(x-1,x+1)$ in one sieve.

Comment: Can you please detail it,  I seriously don't understand

Comment: Some manipulation would change the above equation to $x^2-1=(s+1)(s^2+s+t-1)$, and then it is possible to apply some divisibility logic using $s+1$ to show that twin prime pairs are never represented by such an $x^2-1$ in that equation, while any time either of $x-1,x+1$ is not prime there is a pair $s,t$ such that the equation holds.

Comment: Also $x^2=m^4+mn+n$ is another sieve with the same effect, and approximately the same degree separation as for the "Suzuki sieve" you are using.